# MySQL Inner Join Where Date less than X but with no higher values

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I want to get the latest row from a table but only where that row has a date less than X and no other greater linked dates.

```
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Document 1 |
| 2  | Document 2 |
+----+------------+

+----+------------+------------+
| id | documentId | date       |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1          | 2016-10-20 |
| 2  | 2          | 2016-10-20 |
| 3  | 2          | 2016-12-20 | Row I want returned
+----+------------+------------+
```

I'm currently trying an inner join to sub select the table, and using order by to get the latest row.

Where I run into a problem is when I use WHERE date < X.

```
SELECT documents.id, upload.date AS expirydate FROM documents
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, typeID, date
    FROM uploads WHERE type = 'document' ORDER BY id DESC)
        as upload ON documents.id = upload.typeID
WHERE upload.date < '2016-11-20'
GROUP BY documents.id
```

*Returns date of 2016-10-20*

If there are two rows linked to the document.id within uploads, it will return the earlier one if it is before '2016-11-20'. I want it to return nothing as it isn't the latest row. I can understand why it works the way it does, I just can't figure out a way of doing what I need.

```
SELECT documents.id,
   (SELECT date FROM uploads
        WHERE type = 'document'
            AND typeID = documents.id
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1) AS expirydate
FROM documents
WHERE expirydate < '2016-11-20'
GROUP BY documents.id
```

The above almost works for me, but the WHERE doesn't work as expirydate is an unknown column to the parent query. I tried moving the date clause to the subquery such as below.

```
SELECT documents.id,
    (SELECT date FROM uploads
        WHERE type = 'document'
            AND typeID = documents.id
            AND date < '2016-11-20'
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1) AS expirydate
FROM documents
GROUP BY documents.id
```

But again that pulls an earlier date and I couldn't see a way to add a clause which would read AND later row NOT EXISTS in effect.

I've just tried the below which sort of gives me the result I'm after, but the problem is it gives a result. If the solution were an inner join, it wouldn't give a result because the date field would be NULL.

```
SELECT documents.id,
    (SELECT date FROM uploads
        WHERE type = 'document'
            AND typeID = documents.id
            AND date < '2016-11-20'
            AND typeID NOT IN (SELECT typeID FROM uploads WHERE id > u.id)
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1) AS expirydate
FROM documents
GROUP BY documents.id
```

*Returns date of 2016-12-20*

**I have now found the following query works the way I want, however I'm not sure if this is the fastest or best practice way to achieve this. There may be a better way, I'm not sure.**

```
SELECT documents.id, upload.description AS expirydate
FROM documents
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id, typeID, description
        FROM uploads WHERE type = 'document')
            as upload ON documents.id = upload.typeID
WHERE upload.description < '2017-12-20'
    AND upload.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM uploads
                    WHERE type = 'document' AND typeID = documents.id)
    AND documents.id = 74
GROUP BY documents.id
```

Comment: This is the single most frequently asked question under this tag. Occasionally, it's correctly answered too. Personally, I like the approach provided in the manual under the heading 'uncorrelated subquery': http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html . If you're still struggling, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry many thanks for your first link, it put me on the right path to my latest trial. Your thoughts on that would be appreciated there might still be better ways.

Comment: Yeah, a correlated subquery. Not how I'd do it.

Comment: I tried to get my head around how I'd do this as an uncorrelated query but because the example in the link is using the same table for the join, it makes it hard to see how you'd do it using two different tables.

Comment: Well, it's just another join- but whatever, right?